# Find all the elements of the $\mathbb{Z}[i] / \langle 2-2i \rangle $

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

For the ring $\mathbb{Z}[i] / \langle 2-2i \rangle $, I'll say the $I = \langle 2-2i \rangle$ and $R = \mathbb{Z}[i]$. It is clear that $\vert R /I \vert =8$ and $char(R/I) =4$. But the question in my books required "All the elements of the $R/I$"!

$R/I =\{ (a+bi)+I \vert 0\leq N(a+bi) < 8\}$ . (Here the $a+b i \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$)

So the $(a,b) \in \{(0,0),(\pm1,0), (0, \pm1),   (\pm1, \pm1),  (0, \pm2),  (\pm2, 0),  (\pm2, \pm1),  (\pm1, \pm2)\}$. There are $21$ possibilities which can the $(a,b)$ can be.

Firstly Focusing on the $2=2i$ in $R/I$, I got the below.

$(2,0 ) = (0, 2)$, $(-2,0) = (0,-2)$, $(0, 2) = (-2, 0)$ and $(0, -2) = (2, 0)$ since the $2=2i, -2=-2i, 2i=-2$ and $-2i=2$

Hence, $(2,0) = (0,2) =(-2,0) =(0,-2)$ in $R/I $

By the way it is clear $4 \in I$. We get $(2, \pm1)=   (-2, \pm1)$

Moreover $I$ is the ideal of the $R$, $4i \in I$. Again, We get $(\pm 1, 2)=   (\pm1, -2)$

So the $(a,b) \in \{(0,0),(\pm1,0), (0, \pm1),   (\pm1, \pm1),  (2, 0),  (2, \pm1),  (\pm1, 2)\}$

But the serious problem is I can't do next step anymore. I've stuck this question. I can't eliminate the same element to make the order $8$. What should I do next? Plus Are there any different idea or methods for finding the elements?  My method is so complicated. Please help me.

p.s.) My book only suggest the answer without any solutions. It said, $R/I = \{I, 1+I, 2+I, 3+I, 1\pm i + I , 2\pm i + I\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can continue with your solution by adding multiples of $2-2i$ to obtain the required list. For example, $(-1-i)+i(2-2i)=1+i$, so that $1+i+I$ and $-1-i+I$ are the same.